# Script that reads input from terminal. How to tell the script to print to both tty and stdout in case it is called with a stdout redirection?

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, tty, stdin

I have a script which asks users for input in the terminal, therefore in case the script is called with stdout redirected to a file, the user has no context on the prompt. So I would like to duplicate stdout to both sites.

The script outputs a calculus so it still makes sense to allow stdout redirection.

But if stdin is provided (kind of yes command or non-interactive context like a cron), it makes sense the output IS perfectly allowed to not being required in the tty.

So I would like to do some kind of logic like:

```
If (test -t 0 && ! test -t 1);
  // Tell stdout to print everything  to tty as well
```

Is this possible? Or is it fundamentally inappropriate?

Comment: Prompts usually go on stderr, not stdout as it shouldn't be part of the normal/useful output of your command. See for instance the one issued by `read -p prompt`, or the `PS1`, `PS2` prompts in various shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if it's the prompt string you're concerned about, it should usually go to stderr. That's what most utilities do when they issue a prompt. See for instance the `read 'var?prompt` or ksh/zsh/yash or the `read -p prompt var` of `bash`.

That way, it's kept separate from the normal output which you can then safely redirect.

To still do what you're asking and tee the output to the controlling tty as well when stdin is on a tty but stdout is not, in a few shells including ksh93, zsh or bash, you can do:

```
if [[ -t 0 && ! -t 1 ]]; then
  exec > >(tee /dev/tty)
fi
```

But as that `tee` is run in background, you'll likely find that its output to the terminal comes at the wrong time. For instance:

```
$ zsh -c 'exec > >(tee /dev/tty); print before; read "var?Prompt: "; print -r "after: $var"' > /dev/null
Prompt: before
what?
after: what?
```

The `before` made its way to the tty *after* `read` issued its prompt.

So instead to do those redirections globally, you'd need to do it for every command, or at least for every group of command in between those that issue prompt or write to stderr or the terminal by themselves, and even then the stdout/stderr of each command would likely be showing in weird order.

```
#! /bin/zsh -
if [[ -t 0 && ! -t 1 ]]; then
  alias -g '{#}=>&1 > /dev/tty'
else
  alias -g '{#}='
fi
print before {#}
read 'var?prompt: '
print -r after: $var {#}
```

(here using zsh's builtin `tee` facility when a fd is redirected more than once).